# How to find the codons that codes for the same amino acid in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have a txt file with all the codons and the amino acids, look like this:

```
CTT L
ATG M
ACA T
ACG T
ATC I
AAC N
ATA I
AGG R
CCT P
ACT T
AGC S
AAG K
AGA R
CAT H
AAT N
ATT I
CTG L
CTA L
CTC L
CAC H
AAA K
CCG P
AGT S
CCA P
CAA Q
CCC P
TAT Y
GGT G
TGT C
CGA R
CAG Q
TCT S
GAT D
CGG R
TTT F
TGC C
GGG G
TAG *
GGA G
TAA *
GGC G
TAC Y
TTC F
TCG S
TTA L
TTG L
TCC S
ACC T
TCA S
GCA A
GTA V
GCC A
GTC V
GCG A
GTG V
GAG E
GTT V
GCT A
TGA *
GAC D
CGT R
TGG W
GAA E
CGC R
```

How do I retrieve these information and make the output in such way that for each amino acid,its coresponding codons are shown. Like:

```
F [TTT, TTC]
L [TTA, TTG, CTT, CTC, CTA, CTG]
```

......

Anyone?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your current code, and what appears to be the problem. (You may want to read [ask], too.) Also, what is the desired output? I'm assuming it's a dictionary, but it's not formatted as one.

Answer (score 2):

MAJOR EDIT: THE VALUES OF THE RESULT DICT MUST BE SETS, NOT LISTS!

If this is inside a string named `codons`, then you do:

```
result = {}

for c in codons.strip().split('\n'):
    codon, amino = c.split()
    result.setdefault(amino, set()).add(codon)

for r in result:
    print r, result[r]
```

EDIT: If you ALREADY have the data in dictionary, just skip the "parsing" and go straight with `dict.iteritems()`, which is an iterator over the items (key-value pairs) of the dict:

```
result = {}

for codon, amino in codonsdict.iteritems():
    result.setdefault(amino, set()).add(codon)

for r in result:
    print r, result[r]
```

Using `setdefault(key, default)` is important because you have to create the empty key-value default pair at the first occurrence of a key.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! But what if these are in a dictionary? For example, codon as keys and amino acid as values?

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you the dictionary you are looking for. But in the future, let us know if this is a homework assignment or not.

```
codon_table = {
    'A': ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
    'C': ('TGT', 'TGC'),
    'D': ('GAT', 'GAC'),
    'E': ('GAA', 'GAG'),
    'F': ('TTT', 'TTC'),
    'G': ('GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'),
    'I': ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
    'H': ('CAT', 'CAC'),
    'K': ('AAA', 'AAG'),
    'L': ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'),
    'M': ('ATG',),
    'N': ('AAT', 'AAC'),
    'P': ('CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),
    'Q': ('CAA', 'CAG'),
    'R': ('CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),
    'S': ('TCT', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCG', 'AGT', 'AGC'),
    'T': ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
    'V': ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
    'W': ('TGG',),
    'Y': ('TAT', 'TAC'),
    '*': ('TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA'),
}
```